# PHP filter/sanitize string with valid less/greater than characters

Tags: php

I'm using PHP's `filter_var` function, with `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` filter and `FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES` flags set, in order to clean some user input, as normal. However, when the input string has a single less than (<) character, everything after the character is stripped. I'm guessing it's because the function is looking for a closing > to complete the "tag".

Is there any way around this? I still want to strip any valid tags and I'm aware of `strip_tags()` but would like to stick with `filter_var` for consistency, if possible. Thanks.

EDIT: so, an example string, thanks to @Random: `<p> this is > to that </p>` to come out as `this is > to that`

Comment: Can't you just escape them ?

Comment: You mean your input looks like `<p> this is > to that </p>` and you want to output `this is > to that ` ?

Comment: Yeah, something along those lines alright, thanks

Comment: The issue is to detect where is it the start of a tag, and where is it a simple text, can't see a way to determine it... except maybe if the symbol is followed by a space, but I don't think it's enough... the sentence `<p>this is a <<test>></p>` would be hard to detect `<test>` is not a tag...